# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: laravel

I am creating an index form that displays some data. Everything is ready but when I make the delete button I get an error "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST."

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::resource('roles','RoleController');
    Route::resource('users','UserController');
    Route::resource('kamar_theresia','Kamar_TheresiaController');
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Kamar_Theresia::find($id)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('kamar_theresia.index')
        ->with('success','Kamar Theresia deleted successfully');
}
```

**View**

```
        @foreach ($kamar_theresia as $tere)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $tere->nama }}</td>
            <td>{{ $tere->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $tere->ketersediaan }}</td>
            <td>
                @can('theresia-delete')
                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['kamar_theresia.destroy', $tere->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
                @endcan
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're almost there! I would use POST for the form similar to this:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['kamar_theresia.destroy']) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('id',$tere->id) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Delete') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and then in your controller

```
public function destroy(Request $request){
    $id = $request->input('id');
    Kamar_Theresia::find($id)->delete();
```

The rest of your code should be ok. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I have considered several times and nothing has happened.

Comment: Apologies, I had the route set to index instead of destroy, can you try again with updated code?

Comment: I have changed and after that I get an error "Missing required parameters for [Route: kamar_theresia.destroy] [URI: kamar_theresia/{kamar_theresium}]."

Comment: same error as Pedros solution, as he suggests, first make sure the variable isn't empty. You can just change the form field from hidden to text to see if it's populated with anything. If that's ok the next thing is to check that we're using the right route in the form

Comment: Okay, understand, I understand where it's wrong. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: No problem, what was wrong? I was going to suggest using action instead of route next.

Comment: I forgot that I have not displayed the ID, because this form has a foreign key. I also forgot to tell about this.

But sorry, it turned out I was having a problem again. The deleted data notification has appeared, but no effect has occurred. Is the code different?

Comment: did you put `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your controller? if you go `return $id` in place of your `find()->delete` line do you see the correct value?

Comment: Okay. It is true. Thank you!

Comment: I already wrote "Illuminate\Http\Request;" on the top of the controller. Then I change the destroy code to something like this:public function destroy($id)
    {
        Kamar_Theresia::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('kamar_theresia.index')
                        ->with('success','Kamar Theresia deleted successfully');
    }

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you do not have your form inside another form. I made this silly mistake and got the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the you're passing DELETE method as the method of your form, and it is wrong, the right thing to do is pass de POST method.

**Check this example:**

```
<form action="{{ route('kamar_theresia.destroy', $tere->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**Your controller should be:**

```
public function destroy(Kamar_Theresia $khamar_teresia)
{
    $khamar_teresia->delete();
    return redirect()->route('kamar_theresia.index')
                    ->with('success','Kamar Theresia deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: I have changed and after that I get an error "Missing required parameters for [Route: kamar_theresia.destroy] [URI: kamar_theresia/{kamar_theresium}]."

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your controller, since you are using the Route::resources, the parameter for your destroy method should be Kamar_Theresia $kamar_theresia. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Make sure $tere->id has a value. This kind of error appears when you are trying the pass a null value as the parameter of your destroy method.

Comment: Okay, I understand where it's wrong. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{{ csrf_field() }}` and `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` into Form.

```
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

Use this into Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
       $delete = kamar_theresia::find($id);
       $delete->delete();
       return redirect('/')->with('deleted','Kamar Theresia deleted successfully');
    }
```

if we are using `Route::resource()` then it will be automatically route with destroy function.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to put slash in action at start:

```
<form method="POST" action={{--here=> --}}"/save_edit_delete_order/{{$order_id}}">  
            @csrf
            @method('delete')
......

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes, I am</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
```

And in resource Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    return 'kuku';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**view**

```
<form action="{{route('command.delete',[$command->id,$command->car_id])}}" method="post">
@csrf
{{method_field('delete')}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

**web**

```
Route::delete('/commands/{commandId}/{carId}/delete','CommandController@deleteUserCommands')->name('command.delete');
```